# number theory quest.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A positive integer "$n$" is called a magic number if it has the following property: if $a$ and $b$ are two positive numbers that are not coprime to $n$ then $a+b$ is also not coprime to $n$.

For example, $2$ is a magic number, because sum of any two even numbers is also even.

Which of the following are magic numbers?  Write your answers as a sequence of four letters ($Y$ for "Yes" and $N$ for "No") in correct order.

- (i) $129$
- (ii) $128$
- (iii) $127$
- (iv) $100$

Answer given was $127$ and $128$ are magic numbers, but how is $128$ a magic number, $2$ and $4$ are factors of $128$, but $2+4$ is not a factor of $128$.

Answer (score 3):

Read your own definition of "magic." $2+4$ is *not* coprime to $128$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a note about this concept. Suppose $N=p^rq$ where $p$ is prime $q\gt 1$ and $p,q$ are relatively prime. Then $p,q$ are not coprime to $N$ but $p+q$ is.

So a "magic" number must be a non-zero power of a prime, and all such numbers are in fact magic.

$128=2^7$ - any number which shares a common factor with $128$ must be even. The sum of any two even numbers is even.

Comment: what about 127?

Comment: @ArunachalamSivaraman $127=127^1$ is a non-zero power of the prime $127$